# Non-exhaustive patterns in function - finding lower bound

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to find transpose of a matrix by slicing-of the first column one by one from the matrix. Seems like I 've to match the pattern "array of arrays containing single array containing single element". Not sure if this causes error. Help me find out where am I going wrong.

```
    module Main(main) where

    import System.IO

    firstCol [[]] = []
    firstCol ((x:xy):xs) = [x] ++ firstCol xs
    --firstCol [x:[]] = [x] -- not working
    firstCol [x:xy] = [x]
    --firstCol [x] = [x]

    restCols [x:xy] = [xy]
    restCols ((x:xy):xs) = [xy] ++ restCols xs

    zipz [[]] = [[]]
    zipz (xs) = [firstCol xs] ++ (zipz $ restCols xs)

    main = do
            print $ zipz [[1,2,3],[2,4,5],[5,6,7]]
```

Comment: What about the cases `firstCol []`, `restCols []`, and `zipz []`?  `firstCol` only handles a list containing the empty list, a list with at least one element containing at least one element, and a list of one element containing at least one element (which won't be reached because it comes after the `((x:xy):xs)` case).  `restCols` only handles a list of one element containing at least one element and a list containing at least one list with at least one element.  `zipz` get's closer with a pattern for a list containing the empty list and then a catchall on the rest. BTW: `Data.List.transpose`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loading `firstCol` into `ghci`, we see

```
λ. :t firstCol
firstCol :: [[a]] -> [a]
```

but in this case

```
firstCol [x:[]] = [x]
```

the `x` in the pattern `[x:[]]` has type `[a]`, then `[x]` in the rhs has type `[[a]]`. But `firstCol` must return `[a]`, hence the type error.